# JOptionPane.YES_OPTION == ENTER on each button

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I have a option dialog like this:

```
String[]  options = ["Yes", "No"]; //button names

int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(singleFrameService.getFrame(),
        "Some Question?",
        "",
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
        null,     //do not use a custom Icon
        options,  //the titles of buttons
        options[0]); //default button title

//if press yes
if (n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
    //make some if pressed Yes
}
```

When I used mouse and press Yes/No - all work fine...
But when I start use keyboard, press TAB to go to "No" button, and then press ENTER - work "Yes" option

Comment: What do you mean, "work Yes option"? Do you want it to do the "yes" option or do you want it to do the "no" option?

Comment: i whant to do the "no", No == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION;

in my code no work No == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION as the "Yes"

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester: Oleg Beat means that when he tried to using the `ENTER_KEY` on top of the `No` option it still process the condition `if (n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
    //make some if pressed Yes
}
`

Comment: @Crazenezz Does it? That's very strange, since I cannot trigger the default button with enter on a custom JDialog when my focus is in a textfield... Could be to do with the fact those textfields had FocusTraversalPolicy, but still... I thought that the order keypress events are handled in is first the button that has focus?

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester: I tried and found when using `ENTER` key the return value always 0 but when using `SPACE_BAR` key the return value will be same like using mouse click.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It all depends on the look 'n feel, AFAIK. In your L&F, "Enter" means "press the default button" (which is Yes). Pressing the focused button is probably done by pressing the space bar.

Comment: focus is on "No" and then press ENTER

Comment: I understand that. What I said is "Enter" means "Press the *default* button". Which is different from "Press the *focused* button". To press the *focused* button, use the space bar.

Comment: It would get some pressure off my back if there was an easy way to get "Y" and "N" to work for yes and no.  There is great resistance to using the space key for the default option.  I know it is standard but most people have never done it - they use the mouse.  I, however, have the unenviable task of porting a 20-year-old DOS application to a more modern platform and people want it to work EXACTLY like the old one - and they don't want to lift their hands from the keyboard.  God help me!

Answer (score 13):

This will make the uimanager handle the focused button. This will allow you to use both enter or space to select the focused button.

```
UIManager.put("Button.defaultButtonFollowsFocus", Boolean.TRUE);
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed JOptionPane to respond to the return key the same way it responds to the space key and this was how I successfully went about it:
I created a new instance of JOPtionPane and called its createDialog method to obtain it's dialog window.

Then I passed its dialog window to the listComponents(java.awt.Container) method below and that did the trick!

```
    private static index=0;
private static void listComponents(java.awt.Container c){
        if(c==null)return;
        for(java.awt.Component cc:c.getComponents())
            listComponents((java.awt.Container)cc);
        if(c instanceof javax.swing.JButton){
            buttons[index++]=(javax.swing.JButton)c;
            javax.swing.InputMap inputMap=buttons[index-1].getInputMap(javax.swing.JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);
            javax.swing.Action spaceAction=buttons[index-1].getActionMap().get(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_SPACE,0));
            inputMap.put(javax.swing.KeyStroke
.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ENTER,0),spaceAction);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to JB Nizet's answer I would like to mention that input handling in java goes this way, if I understand it well:

1. The components that are in the focussed window
2. The component that has focus
3. The component that is an ancestor of the focussed container

All in reverse order of how they were added (I'm not 100% about that but that would be logical). Now, an inputEvent can be **consumed**. In this case, the JOptionPane registers that *enter* is pressed, and traverses through the collection of components that have actions bound to the input event. The `yes` button, as the default button **consumes** this event so that no other components can do anything with it.

The solution to your problem is that you're going to have to create a custom JDialog. Give it a label for message, a placeholder for an icon, and two buttons. Now make the same constructor as the JOptionPane you are using and give each component the text/icon according to the parameters the constructor receives.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to JB Nizet's answer I want to suggest if you can't using `ENTER` key to access the `Yes, No` button than trying to disabled that key. Here some example:

```
public class NewClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    String[] options = {"Yes", "No"};

    int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
            "Some Question? Press space bar to continue...",
            "",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
            null, //do not use a custom Icon
            options, //the titles of buttons
            null); // disabled the ENTER Key

    System.out.println(n);

    if (n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        System.out.println("Yes");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No");
    }


    System.exit(1);
}
}
```

Comment: Although the code does what you describe, as a user I would not be very happy with this behavior. I do not know which OS is used, and which Look-and-feel, but the encountered behavior might perfectly match the default OS behavior. And as a user, I would prefer if my Java app worked in the same way and not ignored my ENTER key

Comment: @Robin: I agree with your statement as user, I'll update my answer if I got something more customizable for this thing.