# Focus on the button using tab key and press enter

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jbutton, actionlistener

I have a simple jFrame with a submit button and a cancel button. Currently, everything works perfectly. User perform action on mouse click. Now I want to press 'tab' first to focus the button then it should fire whenever someone presses the enter key. It should work for both keys. What am I missing here? I am using netbean IDE. Below is a sample of the code that works perfectly using mouse click.

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
         String ws = null;
         if(unitno.getText().length() == 14)
        {
            String substr=unitno.getText().substring(unitno.getText().length()-4);
            if (substr.equals("0678"))
            {
                model.setSelectedItem("Tesla");
            }
            else if(substr.equals("0675"))
            {
                 model.setSelectedItem("Weber Base");
            }
            else if(substr.equals("0676"))
            {
                 model.setSelectedItem("Weber Mid");
            }
               else if(substr.equals("0677")|| substr.equals("067j")|| substr.equals("067J"))
            {
                 model.setSelectedItem("Weber PDL");
            }
        }
        try{
             Double wd = Double.parseDouble(w.getText());
             if(wd<251.43 || wd>253.03){
                  w.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                  w.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                  wt.setForeground(Color.red);
             }
             else{
                   ws = w.getText();
                  w.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                  w.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
             }

             if(ws ==null || unitno.getText().equals("")){
                int dialogButton = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;
                int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Empty field or out of spec is detected. Press YES to save and NO to edit.", "Error", dialogButton);
                if(dialogResult ==0){
                    ws = w.getText();

                    w.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                    w.setBackground(Color.WHITE);  

                    BufferedWriter output = null;
                    FileInputStream fs = null;
                    FileWriter fout = null;

                    try {
                        // TODO add your handling code here:
                        File desktop = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop");
                       // Double total = Double.parseDouble(ba) + Double.parseDouble(fr) ;
                        File dir = new File (desktop + "/WattCPC");
                        if(!dir.exists()){
                            dir.mkdirs();
                        }
                        File myFile = new File(desktop + "/WattCPC/topextimechwidth.txt");
                        if(!myFile.exists()) {
                            myFile.createNewFile();
                        } 
                        fs = new FileInputStream(desktop + "/WattCPC/topextimechwidth.txt");
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));
                        output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(myFile,true));
                        PrintWriter fileout = new PrintWriter(output,true);
                        if (br.readLine() == null) {
                               fileout.println("Model" + "," + "Date" + "," + "Line" + "," + "Shift" + "," + "Unit Number" + "," + "Width");
                         }
                        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
                        Date date = new Date();
                        for(int i = 1; i<100; ++i){
                            String linez = br.readLine();
                            if(linez==null){
                               fileout.println(model.getSelectedItem() + "," + dateFormat.format(date) + "," + line.getSelectedItem() + "," + shift.getSelectedItem() + "," + unitno.getText() + "," + ws  );
                               break;
                            }
                        }        
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(setup.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            output.close();
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(setup.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    }
                    JOptionPane msg = new JOptionPane("Saved successfully", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    final JDialog dlg = msg.createDialog("Message");
                    dlg.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
```

Comment: Use a `ActionListener`...Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Dude, appreciate your aid. However, like I said, above code is just a sample. I only need help to a enter key. But really appreciate that

Comment: Okay, a `ActionListener` will respond to both mouse and keyboard input.  Since you "seem" to be using a `ActionListener`, then one would "assume" it will work, but since we have no context from your code snippet, it's impossible to know what the problem might be (or if there is one) or suggest a course of action that might help you solve it...

Comment: Okay. This is the scenario that I wish my user could perform. User press tab button to alternate between the jtextfields. Then the user continue to press the tab button to reach the save button. User press enter and the items in the jtextfield is saved. if the user press tab to the cancel button instead of save, the jframe is close.

Comment: Okay, and the problem you're having with this is?  What part of that "scenario" doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some look and feels (looking at you Metal) use the <kbd>Space</kbd> key as the "action key".  A simple solution would be to use a different look at feel, personally, I prefer the system look and feel for this reason, it should work in ways that the user is use to for the current system.

The "action" key will call all the registered `ActionListener`s when triggered

If, for some reason, you are unable to change the look and feel, you could use add a key binding to the `JButton`

```
JButton press = new JButton("Press me");
InputMap im = press.getInputMap(WHEN_FOCUSED);

im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0, false), "pressed");
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0, true), "released");
```

A `JButton` already has a registered key binding called `pressed` and `released` which is generally configured for the default "action" key, what this does is simply reuses that, so that when you press the default "action" key OR <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, they will do the same thing, you don't need to do any extra coding.

See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            JButton press = new JButton("Press me");
            InputMap im = press.getInputMap(WHEN_FOCUSED);

            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0, false), "pressed");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0, true), "released");

            press.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestPane.this, "You rang master?");
                }
            });

            add(press);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

This is cumbersome, as you will either need to do this for every `JButton` you have, create a custom `JButton` and use that instead or provide some kind of factory method to perform the configuration for you, none of which are particular pleasant solutions.

The other solution you have is to create your own look and feel delegate and replace the default delegate.  This is not pretty and has it's own issues which need to be considered (like which delegate do you extend from, what happens if the look and feel is changed?)

Answer (score 0):

Use key binding to register the pressing of *Enter* key to the `JButton` as shown below:

```
KeyStroke enterKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
String action = "Enter"
Action enterAction = new AbstractAction(ActionEvent evt){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
    }
};
jButton1.getInputMap(WHEN_FOCUSED).put(enterKeyStroke, action);
jButton1.getActionMap().put(action, enterAction);
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: *"The Jbutton is designed to work with the pressing of Space Bar when in focus"* - Not only is this untrue (for some look and feels), the solution is also really bad.  You should apply a key binding to the button instead of `KeyListener` and the key event could be consumed before your key listener is notified.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for correcting me. yes you should use `keyBinding` to the `JButton` instead of `KeyListener`. I am correcting my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16923982/1614775.
It suggests

```
UIManager.put("Button.defaultButtonFollowsFocus", Boolean.TRUE);
```